# JUnit 4 testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

```
public classPrac4 {
    public static intmax3(intnum1,intnum2,intnum3) {
    int y = Math.max(num1, num2);
    return Math.max(num2, num3);
}
}
```

Check to see if the newly developed method passes all the test you created in the previous checkpoint.
[There is an error in this code and you should include a test to test for this error] **THIS is the part I don't understand.**
Now change the implementation of the max3 to PASS all the tests. A working solution should pass all the tests.
Any help is appreciated.

```
 @Test
    public void test() {
        int y = Prac4.max3(5, 2, 1);
        assertEquals(5, y);
    }
```

Once the incorrect code is corrected like so:

```
int max = Math.max(num1, Math.max(num2, num3));
        return max;
```

The tests work.

Comment: Even though you used bold text, I'm still not sure what you don't understand. You show a test for the error and a fix to pass it, so what is left that is undone?

Comment: @SimonG. it says add a test to "show" the error?? But it works so...

Comment: "include a test to test for this error". This.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are already done. If you run the original method, as shown at the top of your question, the unit test in the middle of your question will fail, thus testing for the error and showing you caught it. You then fixed the method so it doesn't fail in that way as your third block of code indicates.